# Delete some sheets in Google Spreadsheet by name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many sheets in my Google Spreadsheet. And I want to delete all sheets whith names starts with '1234' like( '1234test', '1234some_other_text') using Google Apps Script. I;m not familiar with JavaScript and GAppsScript so, is there any better way than scan throught all sheets? Thanks

Comment: first,  read the api docs. then show us your attempt.

Comment: @GhostKU it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Rubén it's actually quite clear what he is asking. He wants to check all sheets in a spreadsheet and if the name starts with 1234, delete it. He simply asks if there is a better way to do it other than loop through all the sheets. Being new to scripting reading documentation will not help figure these things out, only practicing will.

Comment: @Vy The OP didn't mention any method

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way for what you are thinking to do. As you want to delete any sheets that have `1234` in the front, I guess you do not have a list with specific names. You just need to grab all the sheets and loop through them

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
for (i = 0; i < sheets.lenght; i++) {
  //Your code that checks if the name of the sheet
}
```

Just use the `.getName()` method for each sheet (you will need to use on `sheets[i]`) and just check for the 1234 at the begining. You can read up on string methods to figure out how to do it (even W3schools will work for this much)

Otherwise, since you are new, keep the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) in mind and always go there first to check up on methods to get the names and how to delete sheets etc.